# How to ignore pulse in a circuit

Tags: led, resistors, circuit-analysis

I have a 12v cable that sometimes pass (75%on-25%off) and other times 100%on.

What can I put on that cable so if the input is (75%on-25%off) then the output is 0v, and if the input is 100%on the output is 12v?

Is a resistor what I need?

[image: pulse example]

[image]

Here i want the purple LED only to be on when the brake light is 100%. Right now if is 75% the purple LED is flickering.

Comment: You really need to explain why you're trying to do this, and in what environment. A resistor certainly won't do much on its own - and you might want to start with something simpler if your understanding is not too good.

Comment: Im trying to connect another light to my motorcycle taillight(I want this light on when the brake is pressed). This is how my tailight currently works: There is only a red and black cable. When the red cable is 75% the tailight is dimmed, and when i push the brake the cable is 100% and the taillight is brighter.

Comment: That still doesn't explain enough. LED for what, what is the load condition? Where do the cables come from? Have you got a circuit diagram? Is this for test, or on road use? Do you care about accurate percentages, or just bright/dim? What is the proper title for your question? You won't get a discussion of the problem here, either a good answer to a clear question, or nothing.

Comment: So, you have a light dimmer and you want your light to be fully on only when it is 100% and fully off when the duty cycle starts to kick in to dim it?

Comment: exactly, that's what i need, i think so...

Comment: Hey Sean, I added an image that hopefully explain better my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would do the job. You can probably simplify it even more.

[image: schematic]

Your 12 V tail light does already contain R5 and if you want to switch the +12 V instead of the ground below it, you will need some more things or drive a relay instead with the output of the comparator.

Comment: So, what can I put between the red cable and the green cable to ignore frequencies lower than 100%?

Comment: @shinji14 This circuit. If your breadboarding/prototyping skills are not compatible with soldering a comparator, you should be able to do the same with a relay, two resistors and a capacitor, but you need to find the trip point of the relay in question and tailor the resistor values accordingly.

Comment: I thought it was going to be something easy like puting a resistor or something like that. I think my solution will be to write some code in arduino.  Thanks you!

Comment: @shinji14 Life isn't easy. You can decode the signal in the arduino if you want, but you still need dividers from the 12 V PWM and level shift/drive from the same to 12 V again. That, or relay or the circuit above.

Comment: @winny , for completeness as a future reference, would you care to detail how you chose the values for the first part of the circuit?

Comment: @SredniVashtar Which one? Arduino interfacing or relay interfacing?

Comment: @winny, just how you chose the values of the RC network that creates the almost constant value to compare with 4.9-5 V in the comparator. I guess you had to make assumption on the overall frequency of the PWM signal, right?

Comment: @SredniVashtar Correct. I assumed 1 kHz to give a resonable starting point, adjusted the RC-frequency to something resonable and the R3/R4 ratio to be below the reference level (U1 minus input) at 75 % duty cycle and above it at 100 % duty cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Use a retriggerable [**one shot (monostable)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monostable) that is triggered by the *low*-pulses (i.e. active low). It will stay set as long as there are low-pulses present and become reset (after a short delay) when they are missing (signal input 100 % on).
The reset state then must turn on your "pink" LED.

The time constant (controlled by R1 * C1) of the one shot should be slightly longer than the period of your pulses.

It can be easily implemented by a capacitor, two transistors and a few resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff4vIC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>