# Monitor status of slow-switching (1 second) signal

Tags: capacitor, switches, timer

I need to make a circuit that can look at a signal and turn an LED on or off if the signal is actively switching.

The input signal turns off and on for a period of about 500ms, but sometimes will be on 1 seconds or longer. What I want to do is make the simplest circuit that will turn an LED on if the input is pulsing and off it the signal is constantly on for more that about 1 second.

Comment: Welcome to SE.EE! I know that such a circuit can be made, but completely forget the name of it.

Comment: The solution is very similar to a question I've answered here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/240929/6930. It just needs inverted logic at the output (e.g. use N-MOSFET shwitching to GND instead of P-MOSFET switching to V+).

Answer (score 1):

Hard to get any simpler than below. The pulses drive a charge pump to turn on an N-channel MOSFET which drives an LED. When pulses stop, the gate voltage drops, shutting off the LED. It doesn't matter if the input signal stays high or low. As long as pulsing stops, the LED turns off after a few seconds.

Only downside is that your circuit has a heavy capacitive load on the rising edge. Shouldn't be a problem for most dumb logic. If it's a problem, don't add another transistor like most would do. Just add a 5k resistor in series to limit the current to 1 mA. Hope that helps, -Vince

[image: Pulse stop detector]

Answer (score 0):

Use a retriggerable [one shot (monstable)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monostable) whose time constant is just long enough to "bridge" the period of the pulse signal.

You can build it with a few discrete components (cf. [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/240882/how-to-ignore-pulse-in-a-circuit/240929#240929) to a similar problem) or use ICs like the [4528](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/HEF4528B.pdf) (contains two in one package) <strike>or NE555</strike>.

Comment: The 555 in its normal configuration is NOT retriggerable. You'd have to add some external components to it.

Comment: @Dave Tweed: ok, lets forget the 555. I'll adapt the answer.

Comment: @DaveTweed Well, one extra transistor for the "high for more than 1 second" requirement. The Missing Pulse detector as sketched in the original National Datasheet is an international treasure. ;-)